# Subfolders in .htaccess rewrite rule - for optional title in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two potential paths that could be used:

```
www.example.com/1/a
www.example.com/1/a/this-is-a-title
```

I want to serve both urls to the same php file. I need the title to be an optional GET field that can either be supplied or not.

```
RewriteRule ^1/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ links.php?link=$1&title=$2 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^1/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ links.php?link=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

For some reason the above does not work. It's not serving either of the path options.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: if I get rid of the longer rewrite rule it starts serving the first URL option fine (but obviously will reject the second one)

Comment: Those rules should work. You should try and remove the `PT` flag because it's not needed for what you're doing.